# Adding parameters to Spring MVC Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to achieve authorization for my RestAPI, by letting Spring's Interceptor's (**HandlerInterceptorAdapter**) PreHandle method check wether the user is in the required role, before the scope hits the requested action in the controller. This requires, however, that I provide each action (URL Path) with the ID of the role it requires. This is my current setup:

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

@Autowired
IUserService us;

    //before the actual handler will be executed
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Integer roleId)
        throws Exception {

        String userId = request.getHeader("UserId");

        if(!us.isUserInRole(Long.parseLong(userId), roleId))
            return false;

        return true;


    }

}
```

**And (a part of) the servlet-context.xml:**

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>   
        <mapping path="/" />
        <mapping path="/users/**" />
        <beans:bean class="com.lumi.api.interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor"></beans:bean>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

My question is, wether I can pass in the parameter **roleId** with the bean in the servlet-context config. I can't seem to find anything in the docs. I think I once saw something like:

```
<mapping path="/" />
<parameter name="something" value="some value">
```

But i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set a property using a standard spring sintax, an example

```
<beans:bean class="com.lumi.api.interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor">
   <beans:property name="roleId" value="REGISTERED_USER"/>
</beans:bean>
```

your interceptor should of course include the property, so simply

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    private String roleId;

    public String getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    // The rest of your code
}
```